# Jruby on rails - Torque box vs Tomcat

Tags: tomcat7, ubuntu-12.04, jrubyonrails, torquebox

I am completely new in application server configuration and deployment. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and have JRuby on rails application (war file) that I want do deploy and to be visible from external networks.

I firstly started to read about Tomcat as it is mention in official Jruby git hub documentation but looking around and searching the torque box was offered as solution too.

Unfortunately, I've not been able to find a article where Tomcat and Torque box are compared. The only thing I know about Torque box is that it is based on Tomcat server and it is not good for development due to delays.

What will be the better choice to use for not commercial application and beginner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really you should be comparing Tomcat and JBoss, JBoss is what Torquebox wraps.

Tomcat is just a web application server, JBoss is much more.

This might help: [JBoss vs Tomcat again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668042/jboss-vs-tomcat-again)

Torquebox (aka JBoss) for example includes a message queue and distributed caching.